# Explanation of command :'<, '>

Tags: os-clipboard, cygwin

(I'm really not sure how I would google this. Sorry if this has already been asked and please just link me in the right direction in that case)

I'm using Vim in cygwin environment and marked a line in visual mode using <kbd>0</kbd>,<kbd>v</kbd>,<kbd>$</kbd>.
When I then pressed <kbd>:</kbd>, Vim automatically wrote `:'<, '>` into the command line. I'm wondering what this does and what all the signs mean. The one thing I found using google is from the [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_Windows_clipboard_in_Cygwin_Vim).

```
:'<,'>w !cat > /dev/clipboard
```

Could you please explain this command step by step? I've been working with Vim for about a year now, but I still consider myself a complete newbie to it.

Comment: Consider V instead of 0v$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly, better than Google is to search in Vim's builtin help.

`:h '<`

> '<  `<
>   To the first line or character of the last selected
>   Visual area in the current buffer.  For block mode it
>   may also be the last character in the first line (to
>   be able to define the block).  {not in Vi}.

`:h '>`

> '>  `>            To the last line or character of the last selected
>               Visual area in the current buffer.  For block mode it
>               may also be the first character of the last line (to
>               be able to define the block).  Note that 'selection'
>               applies, the position may be just after the Visual
>               area.  {not in Vi}.

So this represents selected region, and it will run given command on those lines only.

- `'<` - first visually selected line
- `,` - till
- `'>` - last visually selected line
- `w` - write - will use only selected lines
- `!` - use/run external command (instead of file in this context)
- rest is a shell command

Additional reads: `:h v_:`, `:h :range`, `:h :w_c`

Comment: Small addition: `'x` refers to mark x. `<` and `>` are simply special marks automatically set on the beginning and end of the visual selection

Comment: Those two answers came fast! Thanks! I completely forgot to check the inbuilt help. I'll accept this answer (but I'll wait a bit just incase some more answers fly in)

Comment: it **actually** is `:h ranges` not `:h range`! Note the **s**.

Comment: Note the `:` before `range`, or type `:h E14`, but `:h ranges` is also good, it's the same part of doc, it contains the `:h :range`.

Answer (score 1):

`'<,'>` is not a command, but a **range**.
You can **prefix** any command with a range.

If you want to know more: `:h ranges`.

`'<,'>` is always displayed, when you **select with visual mode** and it refers to the selected text.

Basically, ranges allow you to **narrow** an ex command to the range given. Ranges can be specified via a number of ways:

- relative line numbers
- absolute line numbers
- searches
- marks
- visual mode

On a sidenote, you might be interested to know, that `V` visually selects a whole line.